# Creating a new list from a list of tuples in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of tuples

```
a = [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d')]
```

and another list

```
b = [1,2,4]
```

Now, using lists `a` and `b` I want to generate a list `c` which contains the corresponding elements of `a` which are present in list `b`.

That means c should be

```
c = ['a','b','d']
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested loops:

```
c = []
for b_number in b:
    for a_number, a_letter in a:
        if b_number == a_number:
            c.append(a_letter)
            break
```

or a less efficient (no `break`) list comprehension:

```
c = [a_letter for a_number, a_letter in a for b_number in b if b_number == a_number]
```

Assuming the numbers in `a` are unique it will be easier to use a dictionary:

```
a = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
b = [1, 2, 4]
c = [a[b_number] for b_number in b]
```